# How to make a search field in Workspace header?

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

As proposed in the [tutorial](https://github.com/edvin/tornadofx-guide/blob/master/part2/Workspaces.md#modifying-the-default-workspace), I've added a `SearchView` to `Workspace` header:

```
class AppWorkspace : Workspace() {
    init {
        add(SearchView::class)
    }
}
class SearchView : View() {
    override val root = textfield {
        promptText = "search"
        enableWhen { searchable }
    }
}
```

So I need a property to enable that field in certain views:

```
val searchable = SimpleBooleanProperty(false)
```

Where I should define it and how to access it?

And how to implement `onSearch` or something?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a Searchable interface:

```
interface Searchable {
    fun onSearch(query: String)
}
```

Views that should enable the search field when they are docked would implement this interface. You can bind the enabled state of the search input by creating an observable boolean value to check for this:

```
enableWhen(workspace.dockedComponentProperty.booleanBinding { it is Searchable })
```

Then you can make sure the search field action forwards to the `onSearch` function in the `Searchable` currently docked:

```
action {
    (workspace.dockedComponent as Searchable).onSearch(text)
}
```

Now just implement `onSearch` in your `Searchable` view classes and your good to go. You could also clear the search field with an event:

```
object ClearSearch : FXEvent()
```

Listen to this event inside your search field:

```
subscribe<ClearSearch> { clear() }
```

Now your views can fire this event if they want to clear the search field:

override fun onSearch(query: String) {
    println("Searching for $query...")
    fire(ClearSearch)
}

For completeness, here is the `SearchView`:

```
class SearchView : View() {
    override val root = textfield {
        promptText = "search"
        enableWhen(workspace.dockedComponentProperty.booleanBinding { it is Searchable })
        action {
            (workspace.dockedComponent as Searchable).onSearch(text)
        }
        subscribe<ClearSearch> { clear() }
    }
}
```

And here is a class implementing `Searchable`:

```
class Editor1 : View("Editor 1"), Searchable {
    override val root = borderpane {
        center {
            label("Nothing here yet")
        }
    }

    override fun onSearch(query: String) {
        println("Searching for $query...")
        fire(ClearSearch)
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: `enableWhen` breaks the layout and initial view is not docking for some reason

Comment: and I use `tabview`, so `onSearch` is called from the base view instead of a specific tab view

Comment: Post a complete code sample with these ideas incorporated and I'll help you out :)

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/lisovskey/coursach4/tree/master/src/client/src/main/kotlin. See Coursach.kt, Admin.kt and User.kt

Comment: ok, I dealed with initial view docking by moving `add(SearchView::class)` to `onBeforeView` of my app, but the problem of sipecific tab `onSerach` is still relevant

Comment: When you say tabView, do you mean NavigationMode.Tabs? Please post a running code sample that exhibits the behavior and show us what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Following Edvin answer I get:

```
class MyApp: App(MyWorkspace::class)

class MyApp2: App(View3::class){
    init{
        FX.defaultWorkspace = MyWorkspace::class
    }
}


class MyWorkspace: Workspace("My Workspace") {
    override fun onDock() {
        add(SearchView::class) //With this search view gets enable
    }
    init {
        //add(SearchView::class)   //With this search view doesn't get enable
        root.setPrefSize(800.0, 600.0)
        menubar {
            menu("Windows"){
                item("View1").action{dock<View1>()}
                item("View2").action{dock<View2>()}
            }
        }
    }
}

interface Searchable {
    fun onSearch(consulta: String)
}

class SearchView : View() {
    override val root = textfield {
        promptText = "search"
        enableWhen(workspace.dockedComponentProperty.booleanBinding { it is Searchable })
        action {
            (workspace.dockedComponent as? Searchable)?.onSearch(text)
        }
        subscribe<ClearSearch> { clear() }
    }
}

object ClearSearch : FXEvent()

class View1 : View(), Searchable{
    override val root = label("This is View 1")
    override fun onSearch(consulta: String) {
        println("I'm searching")
    }
}

class View2 : View(){
    override val root = label("This is View 2")
}

class View3 : View(){
    override val root = button("Open Workspace"){
        action{
            workspace.openWindow()
        }

    }
}
```

The thing is when I put add(SearchView::class) in the init{} section and dock a Searchable view, the Search textfield doesn't get enable, if a put it in the onDock function it does get enable.

But if I open MyWorkspace from MyApp2, close it and open it again I get a error, since onDock is called again and try to add(SearchView::class) one more time. What the solution here so I can open MyWorkspace from some other window without any trouble?

Comment: I managed to get what I want using a cssClass on SearchView and overriding onUndock function with: workspace.header.getChildList()?.removeIf { it.hasClass("searchview"). But is this method a good practice.